# http header redirect after output

Tags: php, http, internet-explorer-9, opera

while working on my current project, i've found a little curiosity. if i try to redirect the url AFTER any output it still works fine. but according to the php manual it shoulden't work.

```
error_reporting(-1);
echo "test";
header("Location: http://www.google.com/");
```

will redirect me to google without any error. what's wrong with that (mybe my apache config ? dunno ...). it also works with cookies etc.

i'm using IE9 (tested it also with opera) and Apache/2.2.21.

regards Alex

Comment: The output is probably being buffered somehow. The structure of an HTTP request *requires* the headers to come before the content; there are no two ways about it. Try echoing `ini_get('output_buffering')`; if it's set to `On`, then output buffering is enabled by default.

Comment: i don't use buffering at all. this test case is from a blank index.php i only cutted the <?php ?> tags around it

Comment: How about the ini option I mentioned?

Comment: if i do "echo ini_get('output_buffering');" i get "4096" is this equals to on ?

Comment: Yes; that means that up to 4KiB of data are buffered before being flushed along with the headers.

Comment: as i looked up the php.ini to disable output_buffering i found that it's masked out and def val is off ?! now i'm realy confused

Comment: You may be looking the wrong php.ini? Or it could be getting set at runtime somewhere.

Comment: if looked up all three (php.ini, php.ini-developmen, php.ini-production) in all of them it's ;output_buffering ;Default Value: Off . as said before: "it's a blank index.php and there nothing else than the code above and the php start/end tags"

Comment: In that case I've no idea! There's probably another config file somewhere that's causing it, but I couldn't say where. What happens if you disable it explicitly by uncommenting that line?

Comment: it's still redirecting if i use "output_buffering Off" (or "off") ... i've helped myself with a call of ob_flush_clean() at the start of my index. with that it's all working proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the posts of Will & pieman it figured out that there is a std output buffer which i can't disable or bias. to fix this "problem" i placed an

```
ob_end_clean();
```

statement in the first line of my index.php. cause of that my original test code fails (which i expect). it's indeed not nice but necessary. if anyone of you can provide a "better" solution i'd be grateful.

regards Alex

Answer (score 0):

Building off Will's and Ganesh's comments, you can also try [`ob_get_status()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-status.php) to see if you have any output buffers open at the time of the `echo` call. If you do, then your `echo` will get dumped into the buffer and won't be sent to the client right away. Then `header()` can still be called with no error because no content has been sent.

Answer (score -1):

Due to PHP INI settings your data is getting buffered before outputting it. Thts why its getting successfully redirected to next page

Comment: That's not the question. He's asking why it successfully redirects despite apparently having sent content beforehand.