# header() function doesn't work as written in the manual. Where the error can be?

Tags: php, http-headers, httpresponse, response.redirect

I have some problems with `header()` function. It works and doesn't work at the same time.

The manual says:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Otherwise there will be an error.

But I can call `header()` anywhere in the html-script or php code after the output has been sent and `header()` works:

```
<?php
   echo "Output here";
   header("Location: http://stackoverflow.com");    // it works, it redirects to the site
   echo "And output here";
?>
```

Any `header()` works. This one `header("Some-Header: bar-foo")` can set header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>

     … some script here…

    <?php
      print_r(headers_list());      // only one header: [0] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
      header("Some-Header: bar-foo")
      print_r(headers_list());      // two headers: [0] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
                                                    [2] => Some-Header: bar-foo
      var_dump(headers_sent($file, $line)); // bool(false)
      var_dump($file); // string(0) ""
      var_dump($line); // int(0)
    ?>

     … some script here…

   </body>
</html>
```

How can it be? Is there something wrong with settings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [http header redirect after output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811668/http-header-redirect-after-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are the `php.ini` has [output_buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) enabled which is the exception to the rule. e.g.

```
<?php

  ob_start();
  echo 'Foo';
  header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
  echo 'Bar';
  ob_end_flush();
```

(Note: `ob_start` isn't necessary in the script file if the ini has `output_buffering` enabled, but wanted to demonstrate the premise through code)

Comment: I've checked the `output_buffering` in php.ini. The value is 4096. Does it mean it is `on`? How to turn it off? Thank you

Comment: @Green: Yes, either `On` or a number (representing the buffer size in bytes) means it's on. Disabling it as simple as assigning the value `Off`. e.g. `output_buffering=Off`

Answer (score 3):

This could happen if output buffering is on and you write the header
before the first flush. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php#ini.output-buffering

Answer (score 1):

I think your php config file problem, maybe in you php.ini, you set output_buffering to non-off value.